# how to write custom callback function in js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to set message to my callback after get callback of reading file like this:

```
exp.getServerHandler=function (request,response){

    if(request.url.startsWith("/static/")){
        //passing my custom callback function as an input param
        fileReadHandler(request,response,function callback(message){
            console.log(message);
        });
    }
};

function fileReadHandler(request,response,callback){
    fs.readFile(request.url.substr(1),
        function(err,data) {
            if(err){
                response.end("bad request");
                response.statusCode=400;
                //here i want to set message as my callback param
                callback("failed");
            }else{
                response.end(data);
                //here i want to set message as my callback param
                callback("successful");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

but console didn't log the message of my callback! where is the problem? is this the correct way of doing this?

**edit:**

**this code is works fine and correct**

Comment: can you please show how exactly you call your function?

Comment: @AlexanderNovikov which fucntion? getServerHandler or..??

Comment: exp.getServerHandler, and are you sure that u pass it all necessary parameters? because it may evaluate to false in first if statement/

Comment: @AlexanderNovikov im completely sure my fileReadHandler function is called and response to my web browser but part of code that i want to set "success" of "failure" in callback and log it didnt work

Comment: Code is working fine.... __Tested!__ Try code from this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bevwr3Lf/)

Comment: maybe you should not .end() your response before you set it statusCode to 400 or call callback...

Comment: @AlexanderNovikov – That is correct but not _useful_ under the context of this question.. OP is asking for `callback` function..

Comment: @AlexanderNovikov no it doesn't true nothing changed

Comment: @mehdiakbarian – Did you try what I had shared ?

Comment: @Rayon how can i use Fiddle to see log?in my ide cant see any log about callback message but all other logs are work correctly

Comment: @mehdiakbarian – You can definitely copy the code from fiddle right ?That is quiet obvious decision isn't it ?

Comment: @Rayon i cant see any difference between my code and yours! you read from json and i read from file! but i tried your code and still doesn't get message from callback

Comment: @mehdiakbarian Which console you are reading ? From browser ? Please do not make answer this as __yes__

Comment: @Rayon no bro im beginner but not dummy! i run my code from cmd and read logs from there

Comment: @mehdiakbarian – `E:\wamp\www\Express>node app.js
successful` Output of the code I have shared..

Comment: @Rayon can you share your app.js whole code in http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: @mehdiakbarian – http://paste.ubuntu.com/19542341/

Comment: @Rayon  idk why but your code log correctly

Comment: @mehdiakbarian – Do test using `console.log` where your code reaches and whether `if(request.url.startsWith("/static/")){` is `true`

Comment: @Rayon and now my code logs too!! i think i should turn off my laptop put it in refrigerator...tnQ

Comment: Cheers mate! Have a good time....

Answer (score -3):

use this code:

```
exp.getServerHandler=function (request,response){
    if(request.url.startsWith("/static/")){
       //passing my custom callback function as an input param
       fileReadHandler(request,response,function callback(message){               
           if (window.console && window.console.log)
               window.console.log(message);
       });
    }
};
```

1. Check console object, because eq. IE console object supply only if console window opened
2. Use complete path `window.console`.

Comment: The post is tagged with the Node.js tag. Node doesn't have a `window` object.

Answer (score -4):

Try removing the `callback` function name when passing it to `fileReadHandler` like this:

```
exp.getServerHandler=function (request,response){

    if(request.url.startsWith("/static/")){
        //passing my custom callback function as an input param
        fileReadHandler(request,response,function(message){
            console.log(message);
        });
    }
};

function fileReadHandler(request,response,callback){
    fs.readFile(request.url.substr(1),
        function(err,data) {
            if(err){
                response.end("bad request");
                response.statusCode=400;
                //here i want to set message as my callback param
                callback("failed");
            }else{
                response.end(data);
                //here i want to set message as my callback param
                callback("successful");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: im beginner in js but as i know nothing different between function callback(...) and fuction(...)! but i tried and doesn't help

Comment: Yes, sure thing. I was too quick on this one!